# CSS 3 Column Layout change width on wrap

Tags: css, css-float

I have a 3 column layout specified something like this...

```
#column1{ float:left; width:40%; min-width:265px;}
#column2{ float:left; width:30%; min-width:245px;}
#column3{ float:left; width:30%; min-width:245px;}
```

Currently when the browser window shrinks beyond a certain threshold column3 is forced onto the next line.  When this happens I would like to expand column2 to 60% and column3 on the next line to 100%.

I am not looking for a Javascript solution, I'm pretty sure I could do that on my own but I find CSS much easier to maintain.

Also, I need to support IE8-10 and no SCSS available.

Thanks!

Comment: @Adrift Why did you remove the tag "css-selectors" from the question?

Comment: Because IE8 doesn't support Media Queries, JavaScript is your only option.

Comment: @MattKlooster: How does your question have any relevance to selectors?

Comment: I was hoping for a selector based on container size.  Would you consider the answers below with media query a selector?  (Too bad it doesn't work for IE8 otherwise would have been perfect.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and use a different style when browser width is to low.

`@media (max-width: YYYpx) { ... }`

Comment: Too bad IE8 (which the OP specifies) doesn't support media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
@media all and (max-width: 755px) {
    #column1 { width: 40%; }
    #column2 { width: 60%; }
    #column3 { width: 100%; }
}
```

Should work. Look up media queries, you can filter by screen height, width and media type screen print etc.

Comment: Too bad IE8 (which the OP specifies) doesn't support media queries.